# ios detect heart rate

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting heart rate using the camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274027/detecting-heart-rate-using-the-camera)

I need the same functionality as the application Instant Heart Rate.

The basic process requires the user to:

Place the tip of the index finger gently on the camera lens.
Apply even pressure and cover the entire lens.
Hold it steady for 10 seconds and get the heart rate.
This can be accomplished by turning the flash on and watch the light change as the blood moves through the index finger.

how can i start

Comment: I doubt that this can be done because the flash is not in the same place as the camera. If you cover the camera with your finger it will show black with the flash on or off.

Comment: @Fogmeister It can work, and it does quite well in the app the OP referenced.

Comment: I agreed with Jeremy. The first time I stumbled across that app I was astonished by how accurate it was. If you place your finger over the led and the camera lens, and place a finger from your other hand on your jugular you can see that the light through your finger flashes with your pulse.

Comment: Yes Jeremy, It can work, but how to start :(

Comment: Well, I've just download the app... mind = blown! I cannot believe how accurate that is. I was feeling my own pulse at the same time. Amazing!

Comment: @AT_AB You would start by initializing the camera and reading light levels being taken in by the sensor. Beyond that, beats me.

Comment: You'll be able to measure the amount of red in the image use the core image stuff. Based on how this peaks and troughs will show the heart rate.

Comment: please Jeremy if you a sample code, share with us

Comment: It's a LOT of code. There are several WWDC videos that show how to get colour analysis from an image in real time. These samples alter the image and display it to the screen. You don't need to do that.

Comment: Hi @AT_AB, did you get anywhere with this since the question ?

Comment: Yes @Daniel, I realized for the detection code, I'll share if you want

Comment: Please do, I would love to see how you did it. You should put it on Github or something and add a link to it in your post

Comment: ok, I'll just organize the code and I'll put a link Downloadable.

Comment: Hey Daniel, I wanted to put the project on github, but unfortunately my account is locked, so if you have an address mail, pls tell me

Comment: @AT_AB Hi! Have you shared somewhere the code? I would really appreciate if you will help me.

Answer (score 5):

I'd start by using AVFoundation to turn the light on. The answers in the linked post below include examples of how to do this:

[How to turn the iPhone camera flash on/off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882829/how-to-turn-the-iphone-camera-flash-on-off)

Then as far as detecting the light change goes, you can probably use Brad Larson's [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) Framework. This framework includes a couple of helpful functions that you may be able to use to achieve this, including:

1. GPUImageAverageLuminanceThresholdFilter
2. GPUImageAverageColor
3. GPUImageLuminosity

Using the filters listed above you should be able to measure color variations in your finger, and monitor the time intervals between the occurrences of these changes. Using this framework you may even be able to specify an arbitrary variance requirement for the color/luminosity change.

From there all you have to do is convert the time interval in between the color changes to a pulse. Here's an example of how to calculate pulse.

http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Your-Target-Heart-Rate

Comment: You're not the only one thinking along these lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125995/objective-c-peak-detection-accelerate-framework . I did some experimentation around this, and I believe it might not be that hard to use an average color or luminance filter to track the ups and downs here. You might need to confine this to the red channel and use a little temporal smoothing, but then you simply need to find the peak distance.

Comment: Brad Larson, Can you put us a sample code of that pls

Comment: @BradLarson Can you please share your experimentation.